# HTML5 -> Groovy (template) mapping

Tags: html, groovy, template-engine

I am completely new to Groovy. My task is to get data HTML file(front end) and send it to desired set of users (via Groovy). I read a little about groovy template engine and plan to use the `MarkupTemplateEngine`.

I still did not understand how my front end is going to talk to my backend. Groovy will talk to .tpl - template files I guess. So my question is do I have to write for example (there could be other ways as well) write a REST service and then execute backend code?

In short I need to get my basics clear. Please help.

Comment: I'm not clear about your question but... All the fields you have within a html form are passed to the groovy controller through a map called params when the form is submitted. At the controller, refer to the values as attributes of params. For example, params.firstName, params.lastName, params.age, params.gender, params.phone, etc...